# Margin formatting

Tags: margins

I want to change the margins of a document, and I found out that in the code two lines have an impact on the horizontal margins:

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1cm}    
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
```

How exactly are these related? I want to make sure that margins on both left and right symmetrical. For example if I change the code as follows:

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
```

The file will have a longer margin on the left.

Comment: To have an idea of what are those measures you can load `layout` package and then write `\layout` in your document

Comment: The `geometry` package offers a smoother interface to change the page layout. For example, `\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=10cm,hmarginratio=1:1} sets a text width of 10 cm with symmetrical margins
`